# "Meet me" VS "Meet you"

Tags: meaning, word-order

As a student of the English language, I have always considered the meanings of such phrases as `I'll meet you...` and `You'll meet me...` to be identical in nature, since the verb `meet` tends to be somewhat *"symmetric"* concerning it's subject and direct-object.

However, I was wondering if there is any subtle difference in meaning between the two phrases that might distinguish one from the other, aside from the fact that their subjects and direct-objects have been reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be used for similar purposes; indeed, technically speaking there may actually be no difference between the two. However, consider a situation where you're planning a get-together with someone, perhaps for business purposes. 
If *A* says to *B*, "You'll meet me", the implication could be that it's *B*'s responsibility to meet up with *A*. 
If *A* says to *B*, "I'll meet you", the implication could be that it's *A*'s responsibility to meet up with *B*. 
To get around this, you could potentially use "We'll meet each other".

Comment: Of course! It works just like any other verb in that sense: the subject is still the one performing the action, and thus would bear the responsibility. Thank you ever so much for clearing this up for me; I don't know why I didn't see that before!